# Any JQ built-in function returning index of element in JSON array?

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I have created a csv output from an input JSON file.

Since some JSON arrays do not have their own id's, I need to add a unique id in my csv output that will be based on index of current element in its JSON array.

Is there any built-in JQ function returning the element index?

Comment: I found a solution using the **keys** function:     .a | keys[] as $k | [$k, .[$k].s] | @csv for **input file** 
{     "a":[{"s":"aa"},{"s":"bb"},{"s":"cc"},{"s":"dd"},{"s":"ee"}]    } will produces the following correct indexed output: 0,"aa"
1,"bb"
2,"cc"
3,"dd"
4,"ee"

Answer (score 19):

[`to_entries`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries) should work perfectly.

```
jq -n '["a","b","c"] | to_entries'
```

will produce

```
[{"key":0,"value":"a"},{"key":1,"value":"b"},{"key":2,"value":"c"}]
```

Answer (score 7):

There are two robust (i.e., that work in jq 1.3, 1.4 and 1.5) ways to iterate through an array with an index: one is to use keys[] (which works on arrays as well as objects), and the other using range/2.  These two approaches can be illustrated as follows, assuming $a is an array:

```
($a | keys[]) as $i | [$i, $a[$i]] 

range(0; $a | length) as $i | [$i, $a[$i]]
```

Or more succinctly:

```
$a | keys[] as $i | [$i, .[$i]]

$a | range(0;length) as $i | [$i, .[$i]]
```

If your jq has `keys_unsorted`, you might wish to use it instead.

(index/1 is probably not what is needed here.)

Answer (score -3):

As of jq 1.4, there's [`index/1`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#%60index%28s%29%60,%60rindex%28s%29%60) or [`indices/1`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#%60indices%28s%29%60) as outlined in the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/).